# How to create a dictionary from a xls file with multiple rows/columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries from a file with multiple columns.
Basically what I want is to have the first column as the key and the remaining columns as values.
I am stuck on the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pandas import DataFrame

epitope_dicty = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name=None, header=1)

dicty_of = {}
for name, sheet in epitope_dicty.items():
    dicty_sheet = {}
    sheet['sheet'] = name
    first_column_sheet = sheet.iloc[:, 0].dropna()
#     first_column_sheet_list = first_column_sheet.tolist()
#     dicty_sheet[name] = first_column_sheet_list
```

That is the excel file that I have:

```
Name    Col_1   Col_2   Col_3   Col_4   Col_4
row_1   2.001557961 4.068187426 4.03822587  -0.081289848    -0.029738309
row_2   2.075372353 4.055443241 5.082902764 2.01773175  1.06956111
row_3   2.037347173 3.012477155 2.085767079 0.081567704 0.035155619
row_4   2.088449675 4.083901034 4.045767022 1.047520556 1.023808368
row_5   2.029925701 4.042756058 5.07873749  0.039559598 0.021102551
```

What I want is a dictionary of dictionaries like that:

```
[out]:
'Col_1':{'row_1': '2.001557961','row_2':'2.075372353',...},'Col_2':{'row_1': '4.068187426','row_2':'4.055443241',...},...,'Col_4':{'row_1': '-0.029738309',...,'row_5':'0.021102551'}
```

Does any of you have some clue on how can I continue on achieving this dicty of dicty?
Tks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that does exactly that, *DataFrame.to_dict*.

Check this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2],

                   'col2': [0.5, 0.75]},

                  index=['row1', 'row2'])

>>> df
      col1  col2
row1     1  0.50
row2     2  0.75

>>> df.to_dict()
{'col1': {'row1': 1, 'row2': 2}, 'col2': {'row1': 0.5, 'row2': 0.75}}
```